# .Net Reflector erros de compilação

Tags: c#, .net

Estou estudando C# e estou tentando aprender um pouco de engenharia reversa.

Estou com o seguinte erro:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Result = true;
    this.ConfigName = this.textBox1.Text;
    string sourceFileName = new string[] { Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Tibia", this.BaseName }.Aggregate<string>(new Func<string, string, string>(Path.Combine));
    string destFileName = new string[] { Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Tibia", this.ConfigName }.Aggregate<string>(new Func<string, string, string>(Path.Combine));
    File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);
    base.Close();
}
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Func' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Em outro trecho do codigo

```
ConfigFinder.FindConfigs((ConfigFinder.ConfigListHandler) (arr => base.Invoke(() => configcombo.Items.AddRange(arr))));
```

Ele me apresenta:

> Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it

E ainda no codigo

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Result = true;
    this.ConfigName = this.textBox1.Text;
    string sourceFileName = new string[] { Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Tibia", this.BaseName }.Aggregate<string>(new Func<string, string, string>(Path.Combine));
    string destFileName = new string[] { Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Tibia", this.ConfigName }.Aggregate<string>(new Func<string, string, string>(Path.Combine));
    File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);
    base.Close();
}
```

apresenta o erro:

> Error CS1061  'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and no extension method 'Aggregate' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, isso são 3 questões diferentes.

O primeiro é porque não importaste o namespace onde se encontra o delegate [`Func`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534647(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System;
```

O [erro CS1660](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy74she2(v=vs.90).aspx) é provavelmente porque o método `FindConfigs` não aceita um delegate como parametro.

O último erro é porque, novamente, não importaste o namespace do método [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
using System.Linq;
```